# Trying to combine two different attributes into one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that shows 3 different columns. The activity class name, total revenue, and number of customers. My code below shows those columns (along with 2 different prices, student and regular). What I am trying to do is write a query that calculates revenue based on what the customer type is * the appropriate customer type (student or regular). I can't seem to be write the query to distinguish the 2 different customer types and the appropriate price into a 'revenue' column. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_NAME                                          AS CLASS,
       STUDENT_PRICE,
       REGULAR_PRICE,
       Count(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE)                          AS NUM_CUST,
       Count(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE) * ACTIVITY.STUDENT_PRICE AS REVENUE
FROM   ACTIVITY
       JOIN ACTIVITY_BOOKING
         ON ACTIVITY.ID = ACTIVITY_BOOKING.ACTIVITY_ID
       JOIN CUSTOMER
         ON ACTIVITY_BOOKING.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
GROUP  BY ACTIVITY_NAME,
          STUDENT_PRICE,
          REGULAR_PRICE
ORDER  BY ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_NAME
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `SUM` not `COUNT` and you can sum conditional value as:

```
SELECT ACTIVITY_NAME                                          AS CLASS,
       STUDENT_PRICE,
       REGULAR_PRICE,
       Count(CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE)                          AS NUM_CUST,
       Sum (case when CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'Student' then STUDENT_PRICE when CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'Regular' then REGULAR_PRICE else 0 end) AS REVENUE
FROM   ACTIVITY
       JOIN ACTIVITY_BOOKING
         ON ACTIVITY.ID = ACTIVITY_BOOKING.ACTIVITY_ID
       JOIN CUSTOMER
         ON ACTIVITY_BOOKING.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID
GROUP  BY ACTIVITY_NAME,
          STUDENT_PRICE,
          REGULAR_PRICE
ORDER  BY ACTIVITY.ACTIVITY_NAME
```

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly! Thanks! I'm just learning about how to properly write 'case' and 'if-then' statements, so this was a huge help! Only issue I'm having now with this is when I display the NUM_CUST column, even if a row shows 0 (no customers), it will show the Regular price in the Revenue column. How do I show 0 in Revenue when NUM_CUST is displaying 0?

Comment: @D.S. I've edited case statement and now it should show 0. I thought client is either studen or regular and it is not possible to have 0. Cheers

Comment: thanks so much, I figured it out right before you commented. But yours is cleaner ;). You're the best, have a great one.